# How to decode a UDH on an incoming (MO) SMS sent through ClickaTell (interesting challenge for anyone - SMS experience not required)

Tags: api, encoding, sms, clickatell

The background is this: I'm using ClickaTell with a rented number to receive incoming SMS text messages. I'm writing some code to piece back together a multipart/concatenated SMS.  To do this I need to extract information from the "User Data Header", or UDH.  The format of a UDH is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS

Now, Clickatell sometimes send me a UDH that looks like this:

```
050003fe0303
```

And that's fine - that looks like a UDH. All good.  But sometimes they send me a UDH that looks like this:

```
303530303033666530333033
```

Note that this is an alternative encoding of the same UDH as the first example above.

What I need to do is work out why these two encodings are equivalent.  The second encoding is almost certainly made up of pairs of numbers.  So:

```
30 = 0
33 = 3
35 = 5
```

what I don't understand is why the "3" prefix changes to a "6".  It looks like this happens after we get to "8".  I've managed to work out that 66 = f, 65 = e and 63 = c, so I'm GUESSING that the code is:

```
30 = 0
31 = 1
...
38 = 8
60 = 9
61 = a
...
66 = f
```

Can anyone confirm this encoding? Is it something you've seen before? Does anyone know why the 3 changes to a 6?

Yours curiously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII hex codes for characters '0' - '9' are 0x30 -> 0x39.

0x61 is a lower case 'a', 0x66 is 'f' etc.

I'm not sure why you think '9' is 0x60?

You can see the full table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Brilliant! I knew someone would spot a pattern that I couldn't. Genius. Thank you. I was working on a totally different idea for the pattern, but I reckon you've got it.  Thanks!